# is it possible to create a CPT on the fly when a new top level menu is added in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I've look all over for a solution, i'm not good enough myself to code it, but maybe someone with a little more knowledge in PHP might be able to help me.

I basically need to create a custom post type in the admin panel when a client adds a new top level menu link. Is this possible?

i have just the basic code

```
function create_casestudies() {

$labels = array (
    'name' => __('Case Studies'),
    'singular_label' => __('Case Study'),
    'add_new' => __('Add New Case Study'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Case Study'), 
    'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Case Study' ),
    'new_item' => __( 'New Case Study' ),
    'view' => __( 'View Inspiration' ),
    'view_item' => __( 'View Case Study' ),
    'search_items' => __( 'Search Case Studies' ),
    'not_found' => __( 'No Case Studies found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Case Studies found in Trash' ),
    'parent' => __( 'Parent Case Studies' ),    
);

register_post_type(
    'casestudies',
    array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'capability_type' => 'post', 
        'menu_position' => 6,  
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'casestudy'),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')

    )
);
}   add_action('init', 'create_casestudies');
```

i'm assuming this would need be edited to see if a top level nav exists and if it does, create a custom post type with those paramaters

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code that doesn't work for you. Use as well the search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+wordpress+custom-post-type and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+wordpress+custom-post-type

Comment: I have already set up custom post types within the admin panel, these directly relate to a section or page within the theme, but as the client wants the menu dynamic, i need a custom post type to be created when a new top level menu is added. I've been looking at register_post_type()

Comment: You should ask questions about code here, so please add your code. Is your code already invoked when a new top level menu is added?

Comment: Please add that to your question, not as a comment. Thanks! How does this get invoked when the menu get's an adding? (You talked about that, so just wondering where that basic part is)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to create custom post types as user adds top level menu link? Or only one custom post type?

If its undefined number of CPTS, maybe you'd better to store them in a plugin_option or theme option, and when user adds another top level menu item you add a new item to you BD. Then your init function will loop this array creating CPTs on the fly (and keep them created since it runs on init).

If its only one CPT it's way easier, just add a option that stores if it should or shouldn't run your function!

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is helping me understand how I would tackle the code a little, thanks! Still not entirely sure where to start though.

 yes, I'll need to create a CPT as the user adds a top level menu. So essentially that CPT would be called "example" if the user added a top level link called "example"

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about it, bu maybe you can use http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29 since that menu editing triggers "add-menu-item" action. You just have to figure out how to add / edit a plugin_option when you have this specific action :)

Comment: ok, so i'm not entirely sure, but can we use add_action to call a function which checks to see if is_menu_nav exists, if it does, get the current individual link items and add a custom post type to them??? this sounds far fetched to me..